# "Unable to start the Python language server. Make sure to install pylsp 0.19 or newer by running:

Tags: python, atom-editor

[the Error][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/exy4W.pngemphasized text

Hey good people,
I feel kinda dumb for asking this but I cant't get Python to run on Atom on my Mac. I don't have much coding experience so the more 'technical' solutions I found on the web weren't able to help me. I installed the latest Python version and followed a YouTube tutorial to set up Atom, but I get this Error message and I really have no idea how to deal with them.
I would be very thankful for some help :)

Comment: does it work with a different IDE like `vscode` ?

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what you needed to do to resolve the issue. Did you follow the instructions that the error message tells you to install pylsp?